# Add AzureAD ApplicationID in BookinPolicy

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server

Could someone please confirm whether I can add AzureAD applicationID in the Exchange room BookinPolicy

Something like below

```
set-calendarprocessing "Room Mailbox1" -BookinPolicy "0deb4a5b-a50c-6658-253d-d3388c9adada"
```

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Is there anything unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you want to specify a service principal to make it be allowed to submit in-policy meeting requests to the resource mailbox that are automatically approved.

In theory, you should put the object id of the service principal (not the AzureAD applicationID) into the cmdlet.

But no matter which ID (object id of the service principal or AzureAD applicationID) you want to put here, it is not supported.

The supported value for this property is only for user and group:

[image]